# How to fix "Cannot find interface declaration for 'NSManagedObject', superclass of"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can anyone please help me to solve the following error:

> Error cannot find interface declaration for 'NSManagedObject', superclass of

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
```

Comment: If you have added CoreData manually, I would advise that you add this to your projects pch file

Answer (score 2):

Are you missing an include statement?

Are you subclassing NSManagedObject? If so, go [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/LifeofaManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH16-SW1) in Apple's documentation and scroll to Xcode Generated Subclasses. They give you instructions to have Xcode generate class files from your data model.

A suggestion: Core Data is rather difficult, and you should be comfortable with iPhone development before you start working with it.

Answer (score -2):

import CoreData to your `xxx-Bridging-Header.h` will make sense.